# Levelling issue with Anycubic Chiron

Tags: bed-leveling, hotend, anycubic-chiron

I can't get anything from my printer since I change filament (I always use PLA from SUNLU). I changed the nozzle, redo the leveling... Every time now, the nozzle seems way to close to the bed and the PLA just stick to the nozzle and not the bed. I was wandering if I need to change the hot end.

This is me leveling each corner and center of the printer using a flyer from a shoe store.[image: Leveling the printer]

and this is the result when I try to print stuff (actually square to refine the leveling):
[image: Actually printing]

Comment: How do you level your bed? can you provide a photo? Do you have an endstop on the rails or some sort of mesh-bed-leveling sensor?

Comment: Usually I do a manual leveling then I print square in each corner for refining. Unfortunately I can't perform the later because I can't print anything,

Comment: please share a photo of your setup. What do you use to determine the distance to the bed?

Comment: please don't open a new question but [edit] your questions in the future.

Comment: I actually tried but the issue was loading the photo. The button doesn't exist when commenting a question. No idea how Ingur works without the button to load the photo..

Comment: @Benji_90210 You cannot add images in a comment, and you shouldn't add info  into the comments, you just need to update the question by [edit]. This isn't a forum, people ask for additional information in the comments, the question poster edits the question with requested information. Thanks for more info being edited in by Trish, but I'm afraid this is still not enough to diagnose the problem. If you think it is too close, add a G-code line to [raise the nozzle in your G-code file](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4745/cura-set-z-offset).